# Pasar datos de txt a struct C

Tags: c

Muy buenas chicos, tengo una dudilla y no se como plantearla, tengo que importar un archivo de datos .txt a una estructura.
La estructura es esta:

> Estructura:

```
typedef struct
{
    char nomEditorial[TAM];
    int numPagina;

} tRegLibros;

typedef struct
{
    char nomRevista[TAM];
    int numRevista;
    int paginaInicio;

} tRegArticulos;

typedef struct
{
    char titulo[TAM];
    char autor[TAM];
    char idEjemplar[5];
    int anioPubli;
    int prestado;
    char fecha[20];
    char fechaDev[20];
    char dniSocio[9];
    union
        uTipo
    {
        tRegArticulos articulo;
        tRegLibros libro;
    } uTipo;
} tRegEjemplares;

typedef struct
{
    tRegEjemplares ejemplar[maxEJEMPLARES];
    int contador;
    int contadorLibros;
    int contadorArticulo;
} tRegLista;
```

Y los datos del txt van de esta manera:
*Info en las imagenes[image: Imagen]

entonces yo habia planteado algo asi, pero no se como abordar el problema a ver si me podeis aclarar.

```
void Importar(tRegLista *reg)
{
    char ruta[TAM];
    tRegLista aux;

    system("cls");
    printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
    printf("                                Importar Ejemplares\n");
    printf("*******************************************************************************\n\n\n");
    printf("Introduce la ruta del archivo a importar:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(ruta);

    FILE *fichero;
    fichero=fopen(ruta,"r");

    if(fichero == NULL)
     {
     printf("\nERROR: No existe ese fichero\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }





    fclose(fichero);
}
```

Añado informacion en el archivo van por ejemplo 1 libro 1 articlo uno debajo del otro seguidos y sin el titulo en plan TITULO: , AÑO: van directamente los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la funcion fgets para leer el fichero linea por linea e ir guardando los datos en los campos correspondientes de tu struct auxiliar para luego compararlos con el struct principal

```
fgets(aux->'campo donde lo vayas a guardar' , TAM , fichero);
```

El fgets lee toda una linea y al final de la variable donde lo estas guardando te añade un \n , para quitarlo haz lo siguiente:

```
aux->titulo[strlen(aux->titulo) - 1)] = 0;
```

Asi conseguiras que te quiten el \n de la ultima posicion de tu cadena

Un saludo y animo con la practica xDD :))